# How can I fix this “convex” problem ? Is it just a matter of overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, overfitting, supervised-learning, model-evaluation

I get some metrics on validation data while training a model , and in my case the they are :

> (0.25, 0.31, 0.46, 0.57, 0.65, 0.75, 0.77, 0.78, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85,
>   0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.82, 0.8, 0.8, 0.79, 0.78, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.75, 0.74, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73)

They can described like this :

[image]

In my view , the **ideal result** should be like :
[image]

**Is it a matter of overfitting** ?

Unfortunately , I tried few times to change the regular coefficients to avoid overfitting , and adjust learning rate coefficients to slow down , but it was still "convex" .

**How can I achieve the ideal result showed above** ?

Much appreciated if anyone would give me some constructive tips ?

Answer (score 1):

Very often the fact that a learning algorithm applied on a training data set do overfit cannot be changed. Sometimes this issue can be alleviated by increasing / improving the training data set and / or adding more regularization. However most of the algorithms does not change their behavior regarding overfitting.

If you consider more this problem in a more generic way, this has to be the normal behavior. Consider that you have a limited information in the training data (this is the main reason why you are learning) and your proposed model does not always describe accurately what is the mechanical structure of the real model which generates data. Additionally you have no idea how to discriminate in your data between useful signals and noise. You may well learn very little of signal or learn too much and incorporate some noise too.

In the end what can be done for that perhaps is to learn when enough learning is enough. This basically constitutes model selection problem and you try to learn when to stop learning. Intuitively you watch the dynamic of learning and take decisions appropriately.

A final note is that a nice curve like you want might be a sign that your learning algorithm did its best at capturing the problem and remain stable. However that does not mean the learning algorithm is better than others. In that case you might be in an underfitting situation as well.

Comment: Regardless of  "data selection" and "model selection" , how can I increase the peak value as much as possible and make it stable .